# error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: latex, pdf, preview-latex, pdf-tools, doom

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1 on Manjaro KDE.

When I compile a latex documents, it produces a PDF file and opens an emacs window to display it. But what is displayed is some text and not the PDF file.

The `*Messages*` buffer carries an error that says:

> File mode specification error: (error Error running
> ‘/home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/pdf-tools/epdfinfo’:
> /home/user/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build/pdf-tools/epdfinfo: error
> while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.101: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

If that is of any use, this is happening after a massive update to the OS. Earlier, the new window would show the PDF file.

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Install the poppler library I guess? On Fedora, I do `dnf install poppler poppler-dev` but the names of the packages depend on the distribution, so you'll have to figure out what Manjaro calls them.

Comment: If you uninstall and re-install the pdf-tools package it should update its required packages for you.

Comment: Or do `M-: (pdf-tools-install nil nil nil t)`.  The final t tells it to (re)-install system packages.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

Go to `path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-xxx/build` and run `make clean` to clean previously compiled contents manually.

Restart emacs and let it build pdf-tools. Then, pdf-tools works again :)

---

I have also met this problem.

Follow the error message, we can tell the problem is `epdfinfo` cannot find the library it wants, which is `libpoppler.so.101`.

After check the directory `/usr/lib/` I found there is no `libpoppler.so.101`, instead, we get `libpoppler.so.102`.
Then I checked the pamac history and found the `poppler` related packages were updated from `0.90.1-1` to `20.08.1-1`.
I think this is why `libpoppler.so` updated from 101 to 102.

The problem here is, after the update, pdf-tools tries to rebuild itself. However, it does not really do the rebuild, which I don't know why.
(maybe make does not find the change of source code so it just skips all the rebuild. sorry, I only know little about compile.)

So, what I did is go to pdf-tools' directory which is `path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/pdf-tools-xxx/build` and run `make clean` to remove these object files manually. I also did `make clean` in the `server` subdirectory under `build`, but I am not sure if it is necessary. Then reopen emacs and let it rebuild the pdf-tools (or run `pdf-tools-install`, to rebuild it manually).

Now, pdf-tools works again.

Hope this can help.

Comment: There's no such path on my system. I use doom emacs.

Comment: @Soap Sorry, I don't know where doom emacs put these files. However, have you tried the `doom build` command to ask doom to recompile all packages?

Comment: No, but uninstalling and installing pdf tools (by commenting and uncommenting the pdf line in init.el) worked! build may also have worked, I think

Comment: Thank you, simply running `pdf-tools-install` and restarting Emacs solved it for me :)